# SQL Conditional join inside a function

Tags: sql, sql-server

This question has been asked many times on SO but I never quite found the answer to it, they are mostly solutions to avoid the problem altogether.
I'm working with SQL MS and I'm trying to build a query inside a function (for security reasons) that will either return a table or it's unnested version by country.

meaning that the function should either be

```
SELECT * FROM SALES AS S
```

or

```
SELECT 
    S.*,
    C.Country,
    C.CountryPercentage * S.AmountWithouthVAT as CountryValue   
FROM SALES AS S
INNER JOIN CountryAllocation AS C ON S.CountryAllocationID = C.CountryAllocationID
```

(the fact that this join will make a single row into many rows is why I don't simply use the above one. And the reason why I don't make the join outside the function is because the person running the function will not have access to either of the tables. Also note that because of the way permissions in SQL Server work a dynamic query will require permission evaluation, meaning that is not a feasible option unless I'm to develop a structure around certificates)

So, now I got 2 problems:

1. The output table might or might not have the columns `Country` and `CountryValue` causing problems when defining the output type of the function
2. The actual way to have a function parameter to switch between the 2 versions of the table.

I've got a solution, but this code pains my eyes to look upon:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_I_view] (@Type int)
RETURNS @OutTable TABLE
(
    SaleID int,
    AmountWithouthVAT decimal(18, 2),
    Country varchar(50),
    AlocationPercentage decimal(18, 2)
)
AS
BEGIN
    WITH
        Out1 AS
            (
                SELECT 
                    S.*,
                    NULL as Country,
                    NULL as AlocationPercentage
                FROM Sales AS S
                WHERE @Type = 1
            ),
        Out2 AS
            (
                SELECT 
                    S.*,
                    C.Country,
                    C.CountryPercentage * S.AmountWithouthVAT as CountryValue
                FROM SALES AS S
                INNER JOIN CountryAllocation AS C ON S.CountryAllocationID = C.CountryAllocationID
                WHERE @Type = 2
            )
        INSERT INTO @OutTable
            SELECT * FROM Out1
            UNION ALL 
            SELECT * FROM Out2
    RETURN
END
GO
```

so, I can't exactly fix the first problem, only worked around it by making `SELECT * from [INV].[fn_I_ViewAllMyInvoices](1)` still return those 2 extra columns with `NULL` and I didn't fix the second problem either, as I'm calculating both queries when I only needed 1 of them (and as you can expect this is a demo code, the real deal is way more complex)

Is there any way to improve this code?/solve the problem in a different way? performance, readability as well as maintenance improvements are all welcome

Comment: I table-valued function returns a table in a fixed format.  Period.  You cannot change the format based on parameters.  Learn to love the `NULL` values.

Comment: Switch to a proc

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to calculate both.  Just do:

```
BEGIN
    IF @type = 1
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @OutTable
            SELECT S.*, NULL as Country, NULL as AlocationPercentage
            FROM Sales s;
    END;
    ELSE 
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @OutTable
            SELECT S.*, C.Country, C.CountryPercentage * S.AmountWithouthVAT as CountryValue
            FROM SALES S JOIN
                 CountryAllocation C
                 ON S.CountryAllocationID = C.CountryAllocationID;
    END;
    RETURN;
END;
```

Comment: what if sales is by itself a big chunk of code? does that mean I need to duplicate the code that produces sales on both parts of the IF?
what I have is actually "WITH SALES AS (...), Out1 AS (...), Out2 AS (...) SELECT ..."
so they both use the same code that calculated sales

Comment: @user13900375 . . . Well, you were duplicating the code in your CTEs so I don't see that as a concern.  If that is a concern, I would suggest asking a *new* question.